# Can I restore my HTC Hero to its stock ROM?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, stock-android, unrooting, htc-hero

I have a rooted HTC Hero with the latest Cyanogen mod installed on it.

I'd like to get it back to its stock status, restoring the original, official ROM and unrooting it. Is this possible? I have found [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=559622) with what seems to be stock ROMs, however, I don't know whether that will do the job and also unroot the phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install a completely original ROM for the device, it will be unrooted. flashing the correct Stock ROM for your device will revert it back to its original factory state. Remember to Wipe both the Cache and Data when you flash.

in the post you linked it also says:

> Notice: These are NOT rooted, and contain radio/hboot rom updates